# Add source tags in HTML just as text

Tags: html

I need to display some html/php on my website for the users to see, but not actually run, just show up as text.

**I just need something that will work like this below**

```
<table> <div> <p>
```

Comment: Something like this `&lt;p&gt;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `<` to show up as data instead of meaning *start of tag*, use `&lt;`. For `&` use `&amp;`. Nothing else needs changing in a text node.

Comment: You can also fake a `html_entities_encode()` function, by chaining replace functions; `str.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;");`-etc. :)

Comment: @Allendar — There's no mention of PHP or JavaScript in the question.

Comment: That's why it's not an answer :P. You got a point tho :) Just trying to add a simplified option, might the OP be able to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
‘&’ (ampersand) becomes ‘&amp;‘
‘"’ (double quote) becomes ‘&quot;‘
”’ (single quote) becomes ‘&#039;‘
‘<’ (less than) becomes ‘&lt;‘
‘>’ (greater than) becomes ‘&gt;‘
```

In your case

```
&lt;table&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;p&gt;
```

becomes

<table> <div> <p>

Answer (score 0):

for print `<table>` use `&lt;table&gt;`

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp